# What's the meaning of どんどんいくぞ/わよ?

Tags: meaning

I might, for example, come across one of these lines after a battle in a RPG or whatever. いくわよ・いくぞ by themselves can mean things like "let's go", "let's do this" etc, but I'm not quite sure how どんどん changes this. Based on the definitions I can find it seems to add the element of "continuation" but also that it's done "vigorously". But my question is what does it mean. Is it an imperative like "let's keep it up people" or is it an imperative to pick up the pace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どんどん行く = to keep on going.

Thus "どんどん行くわよ/行くぞ" = "let's keep on going, okay?"